# How to do autoincrement based on last value from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm inserting data from one table to another table. I just take the last value from first table as ID and need to increment from there, so I have taken `MAX(ID) + 1` and doing increment but I'm getting same values

```
declare @t table (ID INT,VID INT,Sname Varchar(10),Rname Varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @t (ID,VID,Sname,Rname)VALUES 
    (4601,1,'Car','maruti'),
    (4601,1,'Car','benz'),
    (4601,1,'Car','honda')

declare @tt table (ID INT,VID INT,Sname Varchar(10),Rname Varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @tt (ID,VID,Sname,Rname)VALUES 
(1,1,'Bike','Dio'),
(1,1,'Bike','Pulsar'),
(1,1,'Bike','Duke') ,
(2,1,'Cloth','jeans'),
(2,1,'Cloth','shirts'),
(2,1,'Cloth','short')

INSERT INTO @t (ID,VID,Sname,Rname) 
Select (select MAX(ID)+1 FROM @t)Id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY VID)VID,Sname,Rname 
from @tt
```

I don't have Identity Property on either tables.

How to get output like this:

```
ID  VID Sname       Rname
4601    1   Car     maruti
4601    2   Car     benz
4601    3   Car      honda
4602    1   Bike    Dio
4602    2   Bike    Pulsar
4602    3   Bike    Duke
4603    1   Cloth   jeans
4603    2   Cloth   shirts
4603    3   Cloth   short
```

Comment: Instead of adding 1 to MAX(ID) add @tt.ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are looking for something like this.

Use `MAX(ID)` of `@t` + `id` for incremented values of `ID` and `ROW_NUMBER()` with `PARTITION BY` to get partitioned values of `VID`

```
INSERT INTO @t (ID,VID,Sname,Rname)
Select (select MAX(ID) FROM @t) + id as Id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition by id ORDER BY VID)VID,Sname,Rname from @tt
```

Inserted Values

```
4602    1   Bike    Dio
4602    2   Bike    Pulsar
4602    3   Bike    Duke
4603    1   Cloth   jeans
4603    2   Cloth   shirts
4603    3   Cloth   short
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an additional table, with data that looks like this:

```
ID     SName
4601   Car
4062   Bike
4063   Cloth
```

Then you can have that first column just be an autonumber/identity, and let Sql Server handle this. Doing otherwise puts you at risk of race conditions.

Your existing table should then look more like this:

```
ID   SID     RName
1    4601   Maruti
2    4601   Benz
3    4601   Honda
4    4602   Dio
5    4602   Duke
6    4602   Pulsar
7    4603   Jeans
8    4603   Shirts
9    4603   Short
```

Again, this ID column can be an autoincrememt/identity column, such that Sql Server handles making sure you don't have conflicts. Later on, if you really need a sequence number per item type, you can use the `Row_Number()` function in combination with a `PARTITION BY` clause to get a result set that looks like you want, and if you want this to be more intrinsic to the data you can build that into a view.

The point is that you want to more cleanly separate the general category of items from the specific entries in that category.

```
SELECT i.SID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.SID ORDER BY i.ID) as VID
    , t.SName, i.RName
FROM ItemTypes t
INNER JOIN Items i on i.SID = t.ID
ORDER BY i.SID, VID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your max id is constant for all records.

You will have to add the row number of that particular row to ID to make it unique.

Also, Manage Nulls (for the first record) by isnull function..

```
INSERT INTO @t (ID,VID,Sname,Rname) 
Select Isnull((select MAX(ID) FROM @t),0) + ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition by id  ORDER BY VID) Id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY VID)VID,Sname,Rname 
from @tt
```